# Convert Youtube iframe to lite-youtube tag

Tags: php, html, mysql, converters

I am looking for the best solution to mass convert my HTML video code into lite-youtube embed tags.
Example

```
<div class="videoWrapper">
<iframe frameborder="0" height="315" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/xxxxxCODE?rel=0" width="560"></iframe>
</div>
```

into this

```
<div class="videoWrapper">
<lite-youtube videoid="xxxxxCODE" params="controls=1&modestbranding=2&rel=0&enablejsapi=1"></lite-youtube>
</div>
```

Do you have any suggestion to mass convert it? (html data is in mysql database)
thanks

Answer (score -1):

Use the following code snippet. Remember to replace VIDEO_ID with the actual ID of your YouTube video.

See details from [here](https://www.labnol.org/internet/light-youtube-embeds/27941/).

```js
  function labnolIframe(div) {
    var iframe = document.createElement('iframe');
    iframe.setAttribute(
      'src',
      'https://www.youtube.com/embed/' + div.dataset.id + '?autoplay=1&rel=0'
    );
    iframe.setAttribute('frameborder', '0');
    iframe.setAttribute('allowfullscreen', '1');
    iframe.setAttribute(
      'allow',
      'accelerometer; autoplay; encrypted-media; gyroscope; picture-in-picture'
    );
    div.parentNode.replaceChild(iframe, div);
  }

  function initYouTubeVideos() {
    var playerElements = document.getElementsByClassName('youtube-player');
    for (var n = 0; n < playerElements.length; n++) {
      var videoId = playerElements[n].dataset.id;
      var div = document.createElement('div');
      div.setAttribute('data-id', videoId);
      var thumbNode = document.createElement('img');
      thumbNode.src = '//i.ytimg.com/vi/ID/hqdefault.jpg'.replace(
        'ID',
        videoId
      );
      div.appendChild(thumbNode);
      var playButton = document.createElement('div');
      playButton.setAttribute('class', 'play');
      div.appendChild(playButton);
      div.onclick = function () {
        labnolIframe(this);
      };
      playerElements[n].appendChild(div);
    }
  }

  document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', initYouTubeVideos);
```

```css
<style>
  .youtube-player {
    position: relative;
    padding-bottom: 56.25%;
    height: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
    max-width: 100%;
    background: #000;
    margin: 5px;
  }

  .youtube-player iframe {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    z-index: 100;
    background: transparent;
  }

  .youtube-player img {
    object-fit: cover;
    display: block;
    left: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    margin: auto;
    max-width: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
    top: 0;
    border: none;
    height: auto;
    cursor: pointer;
    -webkit-transition: 0.4s all;
    -moz-transition: 0.4s all;
    transition: 0.4s all;
  }

  .youtube-player img:hover {
    -webkit-filter: brightness(75%);
  }

  .youtube-player .play {
    height: 72px;
    width: 72px;
    left: 50%;
    top: 50%;
    margin-left: -36px;
    margin-top: -36px;
    position: absolute;
    background: url('//i.imgur.com/TxzC70f.png') no-repeat;
    cursor: pointer;
  }
</style>
```

```html
<div class="youtube-player" data-id="L2mX-Yh9krE"></div>
```